# Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace issue

Tags: java, spring, xsd, gate

I'm having this weird problem of " Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace". I'm referencing GATE namespace in my spring application context. It's an executable jar in which a java class instantiates the spring application context. It works fine when I'm testing it in my local machine through eclipse. But, the problem appears when I try to run it as an executable jar with a java main class.

Here's the exception.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://gate.ac.uk/ns/spring]
Offending resource: class path resource [applicationContext.xml]
```

As you can see, it's complaining about gate namespace.

Here's the application context entry.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:gate="http://gate.ac.uk/ns/spring"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.0.xsd 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd
       http://gate.ac.uk/ns/spring http://gate.ac.uk/ns/spring.xsd">
```

The schema is accessible and is valid.

The executable jar has gate dependent jar files included. Here's the pom file entry for gate

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>gate</groupId>
            <artifactId>gate</artifactId>
            <version>5.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>gate</groupId>
            <artifactId>gate-asm</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>gate</groupId>
            <artifactId>gate-compiler-jdt</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

Here's the java code snippet

```
try{
    AbstractApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/applicationContext.xml");
        this.processor = (TestProcessor) ctx.getBean("testProcessor");
   }catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
   }
```

Here's the Gate documentation reference.

http://gate.ac.uk/releases/gate-5.0-beta1-build3048-ALL/doc/tao/splitch3.html#x5-900003.27

Not sure what's going wrong, any pointers will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you're using GATE version 5.1 rather than something newer?  In particular the latest version 7.0 is available from Maven Central and we have cleaned up the dependencies in the POM to more accurately reflect what you get when you install the regular distribution (from the installer or zip file).

Answer (score 2):

The namespacehandler for the gate custom namespace will be specified in the jar file which this application has provided (gate.jar?), if you look into the jar file you should see a META-INF/spring.handlers file with an entry of the following type:

```
http://gate.ac.uk/ns/spring=*NamespaceHandler
```

This is the handler that your program is not able to find at startup time. Your classpath may be off in the main program or if you have used something to combine the jars into a single jar(uber jar) then the merging of META-INF/spring.handlers file across different jar files could have got messed up, there are good workarounds available for that if you created a uber jar though.

Comment: @Biju..Thanks for the pointer. I did take a look at the META-INF directory of generated single jar file (uber jar). The spring handler for the gate namespace in infact present. # Spring namespace handler mapping for GATE
http\://gate.ac.uk/ns/spring=gate.util.spring.xml.NamespaceHandler . Not sure, what's preventing spring to load the reference.

Comment: Okay @Shamik, but atleast it sounds like it is a process of creating the uber jar that is the issue - it is a little tricky as Spring uses the exact same file name spring.handlers and spring.schemas across multiple jars, so the content will have to be merged across all of them. You can search SO for references to do that correctly. I am fairly sure that is what is going wrong, especially because without the uber jar the flow is working well for you.

Comment: I guess the issue was with spring.handler conflict while building a unified jar. Using maven shade plugin resolved the issue. http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/includes-excludes.html